# Is ほんの一瞬【いっしゅん】だけ redundant?

Tags: usage, expressions

When using the phrase `ほんの一瞬`, I somehow feel compelled to insert `だけ` afterwards. This seems to be somewhat common (over one million hits for `"ほんの一瞬だけ"` on Google), but does it seem silly in terms of redundancy? Since `ほんの` and `だけ` seem to have the same meaning, I'm not sure if I should actually say `ほんの一瞬だけ`, despite the Google results.

Comment: On Google that I know, "ほんの一瞬だけ" matches only 464 examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%BB%E3%82%93%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E7%9E%AC%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=qOloT7SpFOPt0gGAhdmhCQ&start=454&sa=N&biw=646&bih=662 Which Google are you talking about that gave you one million hits?

Comment: @Sawa, the snarkey comment is unnecessary, I searched ほんの一瞬だけ without the quotes and got 9,700,000 hits. 

https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%E3%81%BB%E3%82%93%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E7%9E%AC%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91&btnK=Google+Search&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=

Comment: @sawa Clicking your link gives me 3 million results...

Comment: @atlantiza I think you have something left in the cookies, or something.

Comment: @atlantiza Hint: Does it really give you 3 million results, or does it say that it has 3 million results?

Comment: @sawa I didn't know that I couldn't trust Google's number result. But I still agree that the snarkiness was unnecessary, especially since I did nothing wrong really.

Comment: @atlantiza What many (especially people on this website) are doing wrong is to consider Google (and/or Wikipedia and some other websites) as absolute truth as if they are God.

Comment: @sawa I created this thread because, despite the number Google gave me, I was still unsure about using it. I stated this in my original question. I used Google as a resource (researching my question before asking like I'm supposed to), not as an absolute truth.

Comment: @atlantiza You clearly wrote there were one million hits. I am not (only) talking about whether the pages linked from Google search are telling the truth. I am mentioning your writing of the number of hits as an absolute truth. In other words, you wrote that there are that many pages that hit your query. Is that a truth?

Comment: @sawa, I think you really need to see the bigger picture. No one on this site thinks the number of hits on Google is the Word of God, but it is a good indicator if a phrase is *actually used*. If I type something in and get 2 results for a phrase, then I'm going to guess that it's wrong. If I type something in and get a million, I'm going to guess that if it's wrong, enough people make that mistake to give Google a substantial number. It's like Wikipedia. If you were writing a thesis paper, don't quote it, but if you're just looking for information, it's a great place to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it might be redundant and ungrammatical, but I think I say and write that way quite often... I think I also use 一瞬だけ and ほんの一瞬 but I think I tend to use ほんの一瞬だけ when I want to emphasize 'only'. I think it's similar to たった一回だけ/たった一度だけ, which seem also redundant but I use quite often... so maybe these expressions are rather casual and colloquial.

Comment: So I probably shouldn't use them for something formal?

Comment: @atlantiza-san-- Hmm... ほんの一瞬だけ and たった一回だけ sound a bit casual to me but I think 「'ほんの'一瞬見た'だけ'では、判断できません」「あの方とは'たった'一度お会いした'だけ/きり'で、それ以来、何の音沙汰もありません」etc. can be used in rather formal situations... (But why...? Hmm...)

Answer (score 3):

If you interpret both `ほんの` and `だけ` as 'only', then it is redundant. But notice that `だけ` has another meaning: 'exactly' (This is similar to the English word `just`; it means 'only' or 'exactly'). If you take it that`ほんの` means 'only' and `だけ` means 'exactly', then it is not redundant. But probably the interpretation is a little bit strange: 'only exactly an instant'. I am doubtful whether there is a precise notion of how long an instant is.

Comment: ITYM "an instant"?